# Pass a method to a function before object instantiation in python

Tags: python, oop

I have a class called "App" which has several methods. I want to write a function which creates several instances of App and use one of those methods for each instance. How can I pass the method name as argument to the function ?

Code example:

```
class App(object):

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def method_1(self):
        result1 = self.id + 1
        return result1

    def method_2(self):
        result2 = self.id + 2
        return result2

def use_method_for_each_instance(method):
    all_results = []
    for id in id_list:
        app_instance = App(id)
        all_results.append(app_instance.method())
    return all_results

id_list = [1,2,3]
use_method_for_each_instance(method_1)
```

With this code I get "NameError: name 'method_1' is not defined", which is logical since method_1 is only defined when an "App" object is created. 
Can you help me to change my code in order to avoid that error?

Comment: You need to pass the name of the attribute (method) as a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use function from class namespace.

```
def use_method_for_each_instance(method):
    all_results = []
    for id in id_list:
        app_instance = App(id)
        all_results.append( method(app_instance) )
    return all_results

id_list = [1,2,3]
use_method_for_each_instance(App.method_1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can *pass* the name of the method as a *string* and then you can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to retrieve the method from your `app_instance`.

Like so:

```
def use_method_for_each_instance(method):
    for id in id_list:
        app_instance = App(id)
        method_to_call = getattr(app_instance, method)
        #                   ^ gets callable method from instance
        all_results.append(method_to_call())
    return all_results

use_method_for_each_instance("method_1")
```

Comment: I prefer Arnial suggestion. Using a string means that if you mistype it you could get something other than a method, e.g. if you have an instance attribute with similar name to the method (`halt` vs `halted` or similar pairs) you might end up getting that one and receive an obscure error message instance of getting immediately an `AttributError`.

Comment: I like this answer and Arnial's. Which is better depends on use cases .... perhaps the method name is stored in a configuration file somewhere or is entered by the user, then this one is better.